# Zend Framework IDE

Tags: zend-framework, ide

I am assigned to work on a project which is developed in Zend Framework 1. I just know PHP language and I am studying the Zend Framework. I want to setup the Zend Framework project in IDE. I googled and came across Zend Studio which is paid. Is there any other community edition IDE in which I can work on the ZF1 project smoothly and can someone provide a link for the tutorial to setup the project?

Comment: What you expect from IDE? ZF does not require any special one - any PHP will do (eg. Netbeans)

Comment: My problem is that I have to study someone's existing code first. For that I need something like we do in Intellij or Netbeans by pressing Cntrl and clicking on a class takes us to its declaration. That would be very helpful. Can I achieve the same in the ZF php code?

Comment: Netbeans works with Zend (it even has some helpers for popular frameworks like Zend). It will not always show everything, but I found it very helpfull (and it's free ;)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using Eclipse for PHP: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/mars2

Zend Studio is built on Eclipse and having used both myself, I can tell you they are very similar.  Once you have Eclipse up and running, you can add the Zend Framework 1 library so that you will have auto-complete and framework documentation available in real time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Netbeans IDE or VSCode.
They are free.